# If I use vertex shader to do all operations on object, then constant buffer can be empty?

Tags: directx, hlsl, vertex-shader

The program cycle is

```
Update();
UpdatePipeline();
```

In `Update()` constant buffer for each object, that after transformations, has this object world matrix is copied to GPU upload heap. And in `UpdatePipeline()`, among other things, installed shaders are called. Because we do all matrix transformation using CPU, vertex shader just returns position, right? If yes - is it true that performance will increase?

Now I want to do all transformations using GPU, i.e. via vertex shader. It means that in `Update()` I just should call `memcpy()` with an empty constant buffer as a source?

---

Learning more, I found that I can put in constant buffer position vector `float4` or matrix `float4x4` of vertex, and as a **root constant** choose `ProjectionView` Matrix. The shader will mul one on other. Keep searching... Or constant buffer is one of the root constants? Confused

I don’t understand how to choose what to send as an argument to shader function, like input here:

```
VS_OUTPUT main(VS_input input)
{
...
}
```

As I understand, I can access constant buffer the next way:

```
cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register(b0)
{
float4x4 mat;
}
```

There can be `ProjectionView` matrix, okey got that. But how to send vertex pos to input then?

Comment: Doing all matrix transforms using the CPU means that you're using the slower processor for a critical stage of the pipeline, **AND** you have to update your vertex buffers every frame. No, that will **NOT** be faster unless you're doing something very weird elsewhere. As a general rule: use the API the way it's been designed to be used.

Comment: @MaximusMinimus But I don’t seems to update **vertex buffer** , I update only **constant buffer**(it actually stores vertices, but "vertex buffer", as far as I understand, is another thing)

Comment: @MaximusMinimus and You didn’t answer should I keep constant buffer empty if I want to do all work in shader

Answer (score 1):

It very much depends on the use case. The best option you could do is to implement different methods and choose depending on which is fastest and easiest to maintain for your project. Some points to keep in mind:

- Vertex shader is a very good place to transform vertices as it is designed exactly for that purpose.
- It is very good to keep the vertex shader to a minimum, too, so if you can premultiply matrices on the CPU. For example, View and Projection matrices are usually premultiplied on CPU, so the shader only has to transform vertex with ViewProjection and World matrix. If you don't care about vertex world position, only the screen position, then you can also premultiply World matrix with ViewProjection matrix.
- Transforming all vertices on CPU by viewprojection matrix is usually not recommended, but transforming them with world matrix or skinning animation is not uncommon.
- You probably want to have matrices in ConstantBuffer, because [Root Signature space is very limited](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/root-signature-limits). If you store a single matrix in a root signature, you won't be able to store anything else as it takes up all space of 64 DWORDs. Also, the input assembler (vertex buffer, index buffer) want space in the root signature too.
- You can read data from the vertex buffer in multiple ways in a vertex shader. If you use IASetVertexBuffers(), you will receive the vertex properties as input parameters to the shader function. You can also bind a shader resource view of the vertex buffer and have a `uint vertexID : SV_VertexID` input parameter to the vertex shader and index into the vertex buffer (that could be declared as  ByteAddressBuffer, StructuredBuffer, or Buffer in the shader).
- You can also use instancing, which will allow to render one vertex buffer multiple times with different transformations. For that, you will need to use instance buffers, which are filled with transformation matrices. Again, which matrices you have in the instance buffer or constant buffer are up to you, but commonly world matrix should be in the instance buffer, viewprojection matrix in a contant buffer. The instance buffers are bound with IASetVertexBuffers() call, but their input layout must specify `INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_INSTANCE_DATA`.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. All I want now is just draw **many** objects(currently 10k cubes). No scaling, no rotation. Just draw fast, having 60 fps. I just edited (again) my question, can You update Your answer?

Comment: For that, you most likely want to use instancing. Let me update with a point about it -- done

Comment: It seems, that the thing I can’t get is where I chose what to be sent as an argument to vertex shader function(`VS_input input` in my example). How do I understand conception: I set premultiplied Projection * View matrix as a constant buffer using memcpy each iteration. Then VS_input should contain vertex position. Multiply position on the matrix and return new position

Comment: If understand Your edit right, I should create 2 "constant" buffers - one for view * projection and another for vertex position. What is the sense of `VS_input input` parameter then?

Comment: Interesting, I tried to send as a constant buffer only projection * view, in shader I `mul(input.pos, viewProjMat)` . As a result I get one cube in the middle of screen(instead of hundreds, like earlier). Seems like input.pos is zero

Comment: "10k cubes" — are you potentially trying to build a Miinecraft-like voxel world? If so, you should know that high-performance voxel renderers do not draw individual cubes. They draw combined chunk meshes, consisting of only the visible/outer faces of a whole region of the voxel grid.

Comment: @DMGregory, absolutely no. I am doing physical model that will have even more then 10k particles. It should be not cubes but spheres, by the way, but currently I don’t know how to draw a sphere

Comment: @АртурКлочко The input.pos is not from a constant buffer, but from vertex buffer. Also, try RenderDoc graphics debugger, I'm sure it will save you in the long run if you learn it! ;)